# How many head coaches/managers in women's football are women?

Tags: football, gender

I've been watching the 2015 world cup and wandering what the gender balance of head coaches/managers is in the women's game. What percentage of head coaches in the women's game are female?

I'm interested in numbers for the 2015 world cup teams, national teams in general, and some of the bigger women's leagues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This year 24 teams are playing the World Cup, with 7 female coaches (almost 30%). Considering all national teams, there are 107 male and 64 female coaches (37%).

[According to UEFA](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Women/General/02/03/27/84/2032784_DOWNLOAD.pdf), the number of female coaches in Europe varies from 60% in Bulgaria to less than 2% in many countries.